# MSDeploy "exited with code 6" happens randomly

Tags: iis, msbuild, msdeploy, psexec

I have an annoying issue with MSDeploy. About the deployment just in a nutshell: We have a quite complicated deploy process with 15 WebSites, 6 Windows Services, SQL scripts, etc... The whole process executed with a batch file. Which calls into MSBuild targets. At some point MSBuild uses PSExec to call "msdeploy.exe" to backup and deploy 15 WebSites one by one into IIS on a remote Server.

Everything works "perfectly" except when it's not... The strange and annoying thin happens only with the Backup/Deploy steps. Sometimes I get this error:

> common.targets(30,3): error MSB3073: The command "..\ExternalLibrar
>   ies\PSTools\PsExec.exe  /accepteula \ "C:\Program
>   Files\IIS\Microsoft Web Deploy V3\msdeploy.exe" -verb:s ync -verbose
>   -source:contentPath="" -dest:package="" -retryAttempts:3 -retryInterval:5000 " **exited with code 6.**

It happens "randomly" sometimes I get the error after almost each WebSite backup or deploy but there are cases when a whole deployment runs without any issue. So user permission/rights are not the problem.

I was searching for the Error code 6. Not much luck. According the [PsExec](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sysinternals/downloads/psexec) documentation it sends back only error codes from the executed process. So error code 6 should be coming from MSDeploy. However there is no such an error code for [MSDeploy](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/iis/publish/troubleshooting-web-deploy/web-deploy-error-codes).

Since the issue happens randomly my guess is it's some kind of network or connection related issue. However the remote serve is in the same building on the same network... It should not be an issue.

So my questions are. Does anyone had the same issue? What is: error code 6? How can I make the remote process more reliable?

Software versions:

- Windows Server 2008
- IIS 7.5
- PsExec 2.2

Thanks.